# Question put on hold as opinion based; how can I change it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

@Daft and @Richard have marked my post, [What were James Dashner's motivations for killing off this character?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94744/the-maze-runner-does-this-character-really-have-to-die-at-the-end-of-the-third), as off-topic, as it is more based on opinion than fact. Is there any way I can rephrase the question or otherwise alter it such that it fits the criteria to be on-topic on this forum? When I wrote my question, I was hoping that answers would provide ideas/opinions as to why she should have died, with textual evidence to back things up, though in retrospect, I didn't explicitly state that in the body of the question.

Comment: I edited in a link for easier reference, and upvoted :-) Can't really answer the question though, as I'm not experienced enough here to be familiar with much of the site policy.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks!

Comment: part of the problem is that you try to answer the question yourself by giving the list of pros and cons. If you want a canon answer, you should just ask the question and see what happens. As it stands, you appear to be trying to have a debate on the issue, which is off-topic.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I suppose I was going for a debate-based sort of discussion in the first place. The pros and cons were meant to be a starting point, such that those points were eliminated, and I would get new ideas I hadn't thought of yet. Is there a way to still do that?

Comment: @Jenguinie there is not. debates and discussions are off-topic for this site, period. Sorry :(

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Aww. Is that part of Stack Exchange's whole-network philosophy, or could a forum be created via Area 51/exist that allows more open discussion and debate?

Comment: @Jenguinie you've definitely taken the right "first-step" to ask for clarification and try to improve your question. A question being **closed** or **on-hold** is not a bad thing, *per se*; see [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and [How can I reopen a Question?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for further info. Good luck!

Comment: @Mooz Thanks! I read the wiki page. So given that, is my question now queued to be reviewed, since I've already edited it and it's only been around a day? Do you suppose any other edits are necessary, given that you said that I've made the "first-step?"

Comment: @Jenguinie Yes, as you can see, if you edit a closed or "on-hold" question, it automatically gets put in the review queue so other members can decide whether or not it should be opened. The "first-step" I meant was you coming here to ask a question on how to improve; not many users do.

Comment: @Mooz Ah, I see. Looks like the question is back up now. Thanks for your help, and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Jenguinie Don't be; it's a learning experience.

Comment: @Jenguinie - kill everything on the bottom starting with "Here are my main arguments", put the last line above that (the actual question) in bold, and then you'll have a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you ask a question like "Why such-and-such happen in some novel?", there are only two ways for it to be on-topic and get an answer:

1. You want to know if there was anything written in the story that explains why the event happened from an *in-universe* perspective. ("She died because in Chapter 45 she gets bitten by a poisonous bug and no one noticed".)
2. You want to know if the author has ever made any specific comments about why he/she chose to write the story that way. ("I wrote her death because I felt like it gave symmetry to so-and-so's rebirth story.")

Your question doesn't really look like either of those is what you want. Instead, you've listed a bunch of subjective reasons for and against having the author kill off the character in question, things like:

> Her death was so... disappointing.

or

> the reader could easily distance him/herself from her.

Those are not facts, they are your personal impressions of the character from your reading of the novel. None of those bullet points are helpful in providing an *objective* answer to your question. Instead, they seem designed to invite speculation and debate over which "side" makes more sense, the "pro" or "con" side. And, unfortunately, ***we don't allow debate or discussion questions on this site.***

In fact, there isn't actually a question in the body of your question until the very end:

> Could this have any significance?

and it's not even the main question you wanted to ask.

To fix this question, you'd probably need to gut it. It's probably OK to keep much of the information intact, to explain why you're asking in the first place, but you'll need to summarize it a lot more succinctly. And, most importantly, you need to ask the question you really want an answer to: from what you've written, you're really asking is "Did *James Dashner* ever explain why he killed off this character?"

Comment: Thanks! I've rephrased my question, and am about to post it. It focuses more on Dashner's idea of killing off the character. Please let me know if any further edits are necessary.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned on the question itself:

> I do realize it's very opinion based, but only realized that after posting it. It's more a debate than a question with a factual answer. –  Jenguinie

How do we fix this? Come up with a related question that can have a factual answer. For instance:

- Did the author ever explain why they chose to end the story this way?
- Why did [character] go to the trouble of killing her, given that...?
- Do we know how her death affected [other character]?

In general, any question that could potentially have a *definitive* answer in some interview, spin-off, crossover, or sequel is one that you can ask here.

We definitely do not do discussions or debates. Only questions and answers. But all that other stuff is welcome in chat, as others have pointed out.